# php dom get nodevalue in nest

Tags: php, dom

I have a xml tree like this:

```
<root>
    <a>This is a</a>
    <b>
        <b-1>Im a child of b-1</b-1>
        <b-1>Im a child of b-1</b-1>
    </b>
</root>
```

I tired

```
$str = $dom->getElementsByTagName("b")->item(1);
$str->nodeValue;
```

This output the nodevalue as a whole string, how can I get the nodevalue separately?

Comment: "This output the nodevalue as a whole string". Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @mikeO. I modify the tag inside b a bit.
 From the above output, nodevalue will contain "Im a child of b-1Im a child of b-1".
If I target the b-1 tag then Im able to grab the nodevalue one by one from foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse each `<b>` and their child nodes this way:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("b") as $b) {   // 1
    foreach ($b->childNodes as $node) {             // 2
        if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) { // 3
            echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;         // 4
        }
    }
}
```

1. Traverse the `<b>` elements
2. Traverse the child nodes of each `<b>` element
3. Check the current node is a DOM `element` and not a `text` node
4. Print the child value or do whatever you need

**OUTPUT:**

```
Im a child of b-1
Im a child of b-1
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, you are a genius!
Is it possible to omit second loop as it will get a bit dirty?

Comment: If your document will always conatin a single `<b>` element, you can do it in a single loop like this: `foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("b")[0]->childNodes as $node) {`